# GTK# - Changing propeties of widgets

Tags: .net-core, gtk#

I'm trying to make a program that works like Total Commander (I have to do it for school). I use dotnet for the program and Glade for designing the window. I got the window to load properly, however I am not able to access the ui elements and change it's properties. I gave the element's `id` and `widget name` but it still says it cannot find it and that it's missing propety. Here's code of MainWindow.cs:

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using UI = Gtk.Builder.ObjectAttribute;

namespace GtkNamespace
{
    class MainWindow : Window
    {
        [UI] private MainWindow window = null;
        [UI] private Button _button2 = null;
        public MainWindow() : this(new Builder("MainWindow.glade")) { }
        private MainWindow(Builder builder) : base(builder.GetObject("MainWindow").Handle)
        {
            builder.Autoconnect(this);
            DeleteEvent += Window_DeleteEvent;

        }

        private void Window_DeleteEvent(object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
        {
            Application.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

The `[UI]` part works for buttons, but not for widgets and other ui elements. If you'd like, I can get it on github.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Which widgets do not work? As far as I understand your question, this code is working; you're not specifying any problem, actually.

Comment: Well, this works for buttons but not for widgets like "gtk fixed" "gtkgrid" and other stuff. It just says I'm missing reference, of I try to use the name of the widget. I'll try to get the project on github.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a Button with **id** `buttonClickme` in your glade file,
if you want to access it, you can do

```
Button buttonClickme = (Gtk.Button)builder.GetObject("buttonClickme");
```

Later you can use this object to change/read any property of this widget.

```
buttonClickme.Name = "newName";
Console.WriteLine("Changed button name :" + buttonClickme.Name);
buttonClickme.Label = "New Label";
```

Similarly, you can access any object mentioned in your `.glade` file.

example of my glade file

```
         <object class="GtkButton" id="buttonClickme">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="name">buttonClickme</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_buttonClickme_clicked" swapped="no"/>
        </object>
```